# Silverlight Column Series Chart Width Question

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, charts, silverlight-toolkit

I have some data displaying on charts using the standard Silverlight charts from the Silverlight Toolkit, however all of the data will not display on one graph and there seems to be large amounts of spacing going on in between each set of colums which results in the right hand side columns of data being 'chopped' off.

Does anyone know how I can decrease this spacing and / or tell the graph to have a fixed width so that it fits in all columns.

Below is an image to visually demonstrate the issue.
[image]

**LordCover Edit:** I add on the original question that, I want a direct way to set fixed width for each ColumnSeries. I tried that using

```
<Style x:Key="DataPointStyle1" TargetType="charting:ColumnDataPoint">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="5px" />
</Style>
```

And then, in ColumnSeries markup:

```
<charting:ColumnSeries
    IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}"
    DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}"
    DataPointStyle="{StaticResource DataPointStyle1}"
    Title="Sales Amount"/>
```

But it just gets relative width to the width of the chart and to the # of the series-es.

Comment: Include the Chart xaml and any custom styles you are applying.

Comment: I don't know if you're still interested, but maybe we get an answer now :)

Answer (score 4):

**For Kevin**

Since Kevin originally asked the question, let me just state first: That's wierd.  The presentation of the set of column series is offset from the left hand origin that it should have.  As intimated in my comment many moons ago I'd need more details to try to discern why that wierdness is happening.

**For LordCover**

To answer the addition from LordCover which I don't think is really related.

The answer really depends on what your intention is for setting the width.  I'll answer on basis that you just want thinner columns (bigger gaps between columns).  I've choosen this basis because I can't think of any other reason for doing it.

The code in the `ColumnSeries` specifically assigns the `Width` of each data point thereby trumping any value you might have set in a style.  So just setting the width in a data point style isn't going to work.  In addition if you have multiple series then you'll lose the default palette and you'll have to do all that work yourself too.

What you can do is create a derivative ColumnSeries.  Something like:-

```
public class FixedWidthColumnSeries : ColumnSeries
{
    #region public double ColumnWidth
    public double ColumnWidth
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ColumnWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColumnWidthProperty, value); }
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ColumnWidth",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(FixedWidthColumnSeries),
            new PropertyMetadata(5.0));

    #endregion public double ColumnWidth

    protected override void UpdateDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint)
    {
        base.UpdateDataPoint(dataPoint);
        double originalWidth = dataPoint.Width;
        double newWidth = ColumnWidth;
        dataPoint.Width = newWidth;
        Canvas.SetLeft(dataPoint, Canvas.GetLeft(dataPoint) + (originalWidth - newWidth) / 2); 
    }
}
```

This class lets the original `ColumnSeries` do all the heavy lifting then tweaks Width and Left positions of the data point afterward.

Comment: Can you please help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22347210/scrolling-x-axis-plot-area-silverlight-column-series