# Scrolling X axis Plot area - Silverlight Column Series

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, charts, windows-phone

I have a Column series chart which is working fine.

I have a feature that i need to add to that, i want the horizontall scroll to be enabled to the plot area that is x-axis.

Here is the screen shot:

[image]

If you see the screen shot i have six items, and the bar are very thin because of more number of items, so suppose if i have 20 items then the bars will not be visible at all.

So can we make the X-axis bar scrollable horizontally ?

**EDIT**

ResourceDictionary.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:convertor="clr-namespace:ChartingDV.Provider"
    xmlns:datavis="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
    xmlns:charting="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
    xmlns:chartingprimitives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit">

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="PhoneChartPortraitTemplate" TargetType="charting:Chart">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <datavis:Title
                Content="{TemplateBinding Title}"
                Style="{TemplateBinding TitleStyle}"/>
            <datavis:Legend x:Name="Legend"
                Grid.Row="2"
                Header="{TemplateBinding LegendTitle}"
                Style="{TemplateBinding LegendStyle}">
                <datavis:Legend.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </datavis:Legend.ItemsPanel>
                <datavis:Legend.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="datavis:Legend">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ScrollViewer
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                    BorderThickness="0"
                                    Padding="0"
                                    IsTabStop="False">
                                <ItemsPresenter
                                        x:Name="Items"
                                        Margin="10,0,10,10"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </datavis:Legend.Template>
            </datavis:Legend>
            <chartingprimitives:EdgePanel
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="1"
                x:Name="ChartArea"
                Style="{TemplateBinding ChartAreaStyle}">
                <Grid
                    Canvas.ZIndex="-1"
                    Style="{TemplateBinding PlotAreaStyle}" />
            </chartingprimitives:EdgePanel>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <!-- Chart Style for Phone -->
    <Style x:Key="PhoneChartStyle" TargetType="charting:Chart">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10" />
        <Setter Property="Palette">
            <Setter.Value>
                <datavis:ResourceDictionaryCollection>
                    <!-- Blue -->
                    <ResourceDictionary>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Background" Color="#E85F3D"/>
                        <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Background}" />
                        </Style>
                        <Style x:Key="DataShapeStyle" TargetType="Shape">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource Background}" />
                            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2" />
                            <Setter Property="StrokeMiterLimit" Value="1" />
                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource Background}" />
                        </Style>
                    </ResourceDictionary>
                    <!-- Red -->
                    <ResourceDictionary>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Background" Color="#76D164"/>
                        <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Background}" />
                        </Style>
                        <Style x:Key="DataShapeStyle" TargetType="Shape">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource Background}" />
                            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2" />
                            <Setter Property="StrokeMiterLimit" Value="1" />
                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource Background}" />
                        </Style>
                    </ResourceDictionary>
                    <!-- Light Green -->
                    <ResourceDictionary>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Background" Color="#648ED1"/>
                        <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Background}" />
                        </Style>
                        <Style x:Key="DataShapeStyle" TargetType="Shape">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource Background}" />
                            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2" />
                            <Setter Property="StrokeMiterLimit" Value="1" />
                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource Background}" />
                        </Style>
                    </ResourceDictionary>
                </datavis:ResourceDictionaryCollection>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="LegendStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="datavis:Legend">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20"/>
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ChartAreaStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="Panel">
                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100" />
                    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="75" />
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="PlotAreaStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="Grid">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource PhoneChartPortraitTemplate}"/>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

In the XAMl file:

```
<charting:Chart Name="barChart"
    Style="{StaticResource PhoneChartStyle}"
    Template="{StaticResource PhoneChartPortraitTemplate}">
    <charting:Chart.Series>
        <charting:ColumnSeries 
            Title="Incorrect"
            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Key}"
            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}"
            AnimationSequence="Simultaneous">
        </charting:ColumnSeries>
        <charting:ColumnSeries                 
            Title="Correct"
            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Key}"
            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}"
            AnimationSequence="Simultaneous">
        </charting:ColumnSeries>
        <charting:ColumnSeries                 
            Title="Skipped"
            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Key}"
            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}"
            AnimationSequence="Simultaneous">
        </charting:ColumnSeries>
    </charting:Chart.Series>
</charting:Chart>
```

Comment: You can try to edit the template and add a `ScrollViewer` control there, but in this case Y-axis will be scrolled and hidden too. But I don't know better ways.

Comment: @vorrtex Shall i add my styles here ? can you help me to edit that ?

Comment: Yes, post the chart control template.

Comment: @vorrtex you saw my edit?can you please help me ?

Comment: I haven't managed to reproduce this, because if to set the `Width` parameter, the chart resizes columns so that even 100 columns are displayed, but very thin. Probably you didn't set the width and the chart occupied space outside the screen. Then the simplest way is to use something like `<ScrollViewer...><charting:Chart...>...</Chart></ScrollViewer>`. A more complex way is to open the source code of charts and fix column series somehow.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49556/discussion-between-goofy-and-vorrtex)

Comment: @vorrtex can you please join the chat room ?

Comment: You are defining the datavis:Legend.ItemsPanel and datavis:Legend.Template you need to define the datavis:Legend.ItemsTemplate there should be something like that and set the MinWidth for each column.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have solved it, but i have not made any changes to the APIs,instead i have followed the below approach.

1) We have an option to scroll the entire chart.

2) Make the entire bar chart to scroll and then remove the `Y axis` values.

3) Now create a Dummy layout with `Y axis values` using `Grid row definitions`.This will your root `Grid`.

4) Now inside the root grid place you chart grid.

5) Now when you take `n` no of tests you can scroll the chart, but your dummy layout with `Y axis` values remains constant as it is, so for the user it looks like the bars are scrolling.

Enjoy :)